# May One Turn Left at a Stop Sign When the Car in the Left Street Is Turning Right? (diagram provided)

Tags: traffic, driving, new-jersey

After stopping at the stop-sign at a 4-way intersection (2-way stop), is it legal to turn left if the car on the left is turning right?
[image: Inquiring vehicle is at the bottom of the image]

I am asking about New Jersey law in particular.

Please provide sources if possible.